# && and || in same expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, operators, operator-precedence

In a few cases, I have seen expressions of the form:

```
!form.$valid && 'invalid' || 'valid'
```

Going by left-to-right precedence specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence), this seems to mean

```
(!form.$valid && 'invalid') || 'valid'
```

I am confused about how this returns a string. I would think those strings are `true` because they are not `null` or `undefined`, which would mean the expression always returns `true`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you are not comparing Boolean VS Boolean but:

(Boolean VS String) VS String

You can see a comparison involving one `String` (right-side or left-side) as returning the `String` only if the other operand is `true`.

That's why the return is either 'invalid' or 'valid'.

(The rules is the same regarding another non-boolean value).

Comment: "You can see a comparison involving one String (right-side or left-side) as returning the String only if the other operand is true." - this is the case for `&&`, but not for `||`.

Comment: So in what case would 'valid' be returned? If !form.$valid is true, then (!form.$valid && 'invalid') returns 'invalid', so the expression becomes 'invalid' || 'valid'?

Comment: @Josh The only case where 'valid' is returned is when the form is valid (`$form.$valid` is true), since the expression `!$form.$valid` would then return `false`; and `false || 'valid'` returns `'valid'`.